# How to insert image in db?

Tags: android, insert, android-sqlite

I have a query to insert image to db in android using sqlite.

```
String sqlQuerry = "INSERT table_name SET column_name = ?  WHERE pk_id =last_insert_rowid();";

SQLiteStatement insertStmt = sqliteDataBase .compileStatement(sqlQuerry);

insertStmt.clearBindings();

insertStmt.bindBlob(1, byteArray);

insertStmt.execute();
```

But this shows **sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "SET": syntax error**

How can i fix this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

**-** The idea of storing image in the DB is **not at all economic.**

**-** On of the **most practiced** way of doing is, is to **store the images in some folder on the** `sdcard` and then **accessing that image using the** `path` **stored in the DB.**

**-** Once you have accessed the `path` from DB, **convert it into image**.

**Eg:**

```
ImageView imageQuestion;  // Declared at class scope

imageQuestion.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(/sdcard/myfolder/viv.png));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = ? WHERE pk_id = last_insert_rowid();
```

Comment: No.I want to insert image.Is there any way to insert image without using ContentValues and using execSQL()?

Comment: @DevuSoman: So use `INSERT INTO table_name(column_name) VALUES(?);`, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend you not to insert `blobs` in db, **this will make your db very very slow**

> **Alternative solution is that You should save the image in documents directory of the app and in the db save only the path of the image.**